# Numpy operator for multiple outer products

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

```
import numpy as np
mat1 = np.random.rand(2,3)
mat2 = np.random.rand(2,5)
```

I wish to get a 2x3x5 tensor, where each layer is the 3x5 outer product achieved by multiplying 3x1 transposed row of mat1 by 1x5 row of mat2.

Can it be done with numpy matmul?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after extending their dimensions with [`np.newaxis/None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) -

```
mat1[...,None]*mat2[:,None]
```

This would be the most performant, as there's no `sum-reduction` needed here to warrant services from `np.einsum` or `np.matmul`.

If you still want to drag in [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), it would be basically same as with the `broadcasting` one :

```
np.matmul(mat1[...,None],mat2[:,None])
```

With [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), it might be look a bit more tidy than others, if you are familiar with its string notation -

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',mat1,mat2)
#          23,25->235  (to explain einsum's string notation using axes lens)
```